# Ubuntu, search for a file and also look in all sub-directories?

Tags: ubuntu

If I am in a particular directory path, I want to search for all files in any folder/sub-folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In a terminal:

To list all files in the current directory and all sub-directories:

```
$ find .
```

To search for a file by name in the current directory and all sub-directories:

```
$ find . -name <file_name>
```

Or to search in all files in the current directory and all sub-directories for a particular string:

```
$ grep -R "<string>" *
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want GUI search with subdirectories, use gnome-search-tool .  You can find it in the Ubuntu Software Center (12.04 - precise penguin) or you can install it directly in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-search-tool
```